# Why new public key for every new request?

Tags: multibit, address-reuse

I created Bitcoin accounts using different clients but all clients I tried prompt for new public key for each request. My question is shouldn't be the public key one's identity which one should be able to publish and own even changing bitcoin clients.

Clients always give me new key which makes me feel insecure to use a single key for overtime use. For example I created and want to stick to [this key](http://bitcoin:1N3eYqC7EJdbBBXQ6ntQpmzedVrGeG8iqJ?amount=0.065): `1N3eYqC7EJdbBBXQ6ntQpmzedVrGeG8iqJ` but if I go create another request new key will be generated, **the main concern is should I be sure that this key will always be pointed to my wallet?** As I am not sure and don't have bitcoins to test if coins are received at this address.

I have used multiBit and Android App, none of these give private key as far I browsed. I am looking for an 'identity' to publish for receiving any number of payment, like we can share our paypal email to receive payments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use a different address for every transaction?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2045/5406)

Comment: Addresses are *not* keys, they are public key hashes, but your question is still valid.

Comment: @mark is correct. If you want to get deeper - http://www.samlewis.me/2017/06/a-peek-under-bitcoins-hood/

Answer (score 4):

The reason is privacy.

If you reuse the same key for every transaction, everyone who ever transacts with you can infer your entire balance.

No, public keys should not be identities, exactly because the transactions to them are public too. Your ability to create many pseudonyms in the system the only way through which it has any privacy. By reusing addresses you hurt your privacy, but also that of others who interact with you.

Comment: Means it is not possible to publish your bitcoin identity viraly to get funds like paypal or bank accounts?

Comment: @XIMRX: It is certainly possible and it works fine. It just has some privacy tradeoffs as described. Another option is to publish a link to a web page which dynamically generates a new address for each donor to use (and saves the private key for your use). Or, look up stealth addresses (though at present they are not widely supported by clients).