# Wallet Address(MultiBitHD)

Tags: wallet

How do I see my wallet address? I use MultiBitHD. When I tried to use bitvisitor, it told me to type my wallet address. But, I don't know where it is written on.

Answer (score 2):

Click on 'Request' as if you were going to request a payment. The wallet address will be on the next window. Copy/paste it and then keep the amount requested at 0. If you want, you can delete the request after you've copied your wallet address under the 'Payments' tab.

Comment: why this address (on Request) change every time?

Comment: Hey @ThiagoPereira, check out [Why new public key for every new request?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/38627/5406)