# How do I reclaim misplaced bitcoins?

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

I was given an address to send bitcoins to & it appears the address change but now the deposit did not occur at the address intended & my Source Bitcoin wallet company states there's nothing they can do.  The destination company shows no record of the transaction.  This all happened when the Destination website was implementing a new program & having issues with taking deposits.

Can I get the lost Bitcoins if I know the Send from, Send to Addresses, the Block & Hash numbers?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if Bitcoins are lost](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17694/what-happens-if-bitcoins-are-lost)

Comment: Did the Bitcoin transaction go through? You could go to the receiving company with the confirmed transaction and ask for the amount to be credited to you account. It seems to be their fault for losing the funds after all.

Answer (score 3):

If what you are saying is true it sounds like the company you are working with is at fault. They provided you with a deposit address, then implemented a change to the site, and now having issues with deposits. It will be hard to prove, but it sounds like they misplaced your funds. Your only option is working with them to offer you a refund as there is no way to reverse a Bitcoin transaction.

Comment: As a result of the irreversibility of Bitcoin transactions, the rule is that if someone provides you a deposit address, they are obligated to accept as payment a Bitcoin payment sent to that address. If you made a payment before they communicated a change in the deposit address to you, it's their problem, not yours.