# Bitcoin digital burn

Tags: lost-bitcoins

Is there a way to mitigate bitcoin digital burn if it becomes inaccessible  because if someone dying with their secret key or any of that related reasons.

Comment: Does one of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1638/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/484/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17694/5406, or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/38692/5406 address your question? I have the impression that you are asking either about the general topic of [tag:shrinking-money-supply] or [tag:inheritance-plan], but I’m not sure which one. Could you perhaps elaborate your question?